# Are there any good open source developer machine setup scripts for windows/c# development?

Tags: windows-7, scripting, powershell

I've used [thoughtbot's laptop setup script](https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop) to setup my mac for ruby develpment in the past.

Is there anything similar out there for windows/c# development? Something that sets up IIS, installs visual studio, etc. would be great.

Comment: Not strictly an answer, but I think that most people who do this often enough to bother writing a script simply deploy a Windows image that has everything already pre-installed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is the closest to what you are looking for http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: It is worth noting that v4 of WebPI also supports an offline mode where you can sync the required download files to a network share and then use that as a source to script an install to many computers if needed: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1072/web-platform-installer-v4-command-line-webpicmdexe-preview-release/